# Is the a way to hide the menu from one of the ListGridfield?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

[image: The column that i have selected is just an icon that shows the type, hence i dont want the List grid menu to appear]Am trying to set an icon for a field as one of header in the ListGridField. Hence i dont want the filtering submenu to appear for this field. Is there a way to do that ?

As of now am doing this task using individual attributes. But still the submenu appears.

```
iconLGF.setCanSort(false); 
iconLGF.setCanFreeze(false);
iconLGF.setCanFilter(false);
```

The column that i have selected is just an icon that shows the type, hence i dont want the List grid menu to appear

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try  as per Javadoc ?:

```
setShowDefaultContextMenu

public void setShowDefaultContextMenu(Boolean showDefaultContextMenu)

    When set to false, this field will not show a context menu in its header.

    Parameters:
        showDefaultContextMenu - showDefaultContextMenu Default value is true
```

I don't know exactly if it's what you want .....

Answer (score 0):

With listGrid.**setShowHeaderContextMenu(false);** you can get rid of that menu.